# If real matrices $A,B$ have the same ch. polynomial and rank, and rk$(A-\lambda I)= \text{rk}(B-\lambda I)$ for each eigenvalue, are they similar?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, matrix-rank

Some time ago I had a linear algebra private lesson, and rereading some notes of the professor, I've found

> If two real matrices $A,B$ have the same characteristic polynomial and rank, and satisfy $ \operatorname{rk}(A-\lambda I)= \operatorname{rk}(B-\lambda I)$ for each eigenvalue, then they are similar

but with no proof. Is this true? And if so, how would one prove it? What I do know is that having the same characteristic polynomial and rank is not enough, but I'm not sure why the additional condition would fill the gap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about
$$\pmatrix{0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0}$$
and
$$\pmatrix{0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0}?$$

Comment: Yes then I saw it doesn't matter if the eigenvalues are non-zero haha, I just thought maybe it was "my fault", not the prof's mistake. Thanks!